# Change font of the application dynamically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

We have an in house applciation built on VB.net. User has requested an option where he can change the font of all the controls in the applciation dynamically.
Could you please let me know how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        ctrl.Font = New Font("Arial", 30)
    Next
```

Instead of arial you can write the desired textbox choosen by User